# Enviar cadena SQL a spring boot

Tags: sql, angular, jpa, parametros

Por favor alguien que me pueda ayudar tengo este query en la capa de repositorio

```
**@Query(value="SELECT ordenid , numeroorden, fechaorden, c.nombrescompletos, "
            + "e.descripcion AS nombreempresa, nomtecnico, serie, numeroprod, "
            + "detalle, m.descripcion AS nombremarca, fechacompra, estadoorden, o.estado "
            + "FROM ordenservicio o "
            + "INNER JOIN oficinas f on f.oficinaid=o.oficinaid "
            + "INNER JOIN clientes c on c.clienteid=f.clienteid "
            + "INNER JOIN marcas m on m.marcaid=o.marcaid "
            + "INNER JOIN empresas e on e.empresaid=o.empresaid "
            + "LEFT OUTER JOIN tecnicos t on t.tecnicoid=o.tecnicoid ",nativeQuery=true)**
public Page<ReporteOrdenesDTO> reporteOrdenes(Pageable pageable);
```

el WHERE completo deseo enviarlo desde angular enviando como un parametro
estoy llamando al query asi

```
return this.http.get<any>(
  this.url +
    `reporteordenes/page?page=${page}&size=${size}&orden=${order}&direc=${direc}&buscar=${search}`
);
```

Este es el where que genero en angular

```
**WHERE fechaorden>='2023-03-28' AND fechaorden<='2023-03-28' AND empresaid=3 AND tecnicoid=2 AND marcaid=11 AND contrato=true AND estadoorden='R' AND estadoorden='A'**
```

como hago para enviar la cadena donde esta el where y como hago para concatenar esta cadena con el resto del sql q esta en al repositorio.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda que puedan brindarme.....

Comment: No envíes el `where` desde Angular, en su lugar solo envía los parámetros y que sea el backend el que los acomode.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, con las fechas ya lo hice y esta bien pero por ejemplo tengo un parametro que es marca si se envia una marca saca solo d esa marca pero si no se envia nada saca todas las marcas, ahi es donde tengo inconveniente, por que si va algo en marca debe poner la condicion marca=1 por ejemplo pero si no va nada en marca no debe poner ninguna condicion...